# sending email with admin-ajax.php in wordpress not working when modification of a plugin

Tags: jquery, wordpress

i am trying to modify a wordpress plugin to add email sending functionality using admin-ajax.php, my code in my_plugin.php like below:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_send_email', 'send_email' ); 
add_action( 'wp_ajax_send_email', 'send_email' );

function send_email(){
    echo "send email"; die(); //it could not printed
    if ( count($_POST) > 0 ){
         $to = $_REQUEST['to'];
         $from = $_REQUEST['from'];
         $sub = $_REQUEST['subject'];
         $msg = $_REQUEST['msg'];

        $headers = 'From: myname <myemail@wordpress.com>' . "\r\n";
        wp_mail( $to, $sub, $msg, $headers);
        exit;
    }
    exit;

}
```

and in my form.php

```
jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '".admin_url('admin-ajax.php')."',  
            action:'send_email',
            data: { to:'reciever@gmail.com',
                    from: 'sender@gmail.com',
                    subject: 'test',
                    msg: 'thank you'
                    },
            success: function (res) {
                     alert('The server responded: ' + res);
                }

        });
```

problem is that when i post the request it can't enter in to the send_email() function and not sending any email but it always responded 0 and throw a success message alert like 'The Server responded: 0' ; what's wrong i am doing here? i am stuck at here..

Comment: i have tried this reference http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_%28action%29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was with your 'action' parameter. It should be part of the "data":

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '".admin_url('admin-ajax.php')."',  
        data: { 
                action:'send_email',
                to:'reciever@gmail.com',
                from: 'sender@gmail.com',
                subject: 'test',
                msg: 'thank you'
        },
        success: function (res) {
                alert('The server responded: ' + res);
        }

});
```

Comment: thank you, by solving action parameter issue is now enter into the send_email() function but till now not sent any email, does this relates to wp_mail( $to, $sub, $msg, $headers);

Comment: when i uploaded the modified file into live server it works perfectly!!